# How to update fields in input form when values are changed in react

Tags: reactjs, input

I am trying to write a form so that I can edit a users details and then submit this to backend

I want the form to display the users current details in the form, these can then be left as they are or edited and then on submission the new details are passed to the backend and saved in database.

I have written the backend code `springboot` and this all works fine testing on postman.

So far I have the component in `react` which displays all the users after looping through all the users returned in a previous api call.

```
const UserListItem = (props) => {

    //Chekcing I can access these values from props
    console.log(props.user.id);
    console.log(props.user.handicap);
    console.log(props.user.sochcpred);

    const [myDataObject, setMyDataObject] = useState({
        user: props.user,
        originalHandicap: undefined,
        originalSochcpred: undefined,
        errors: {}
    });

//Update handicap when save button pressed
    const updateHandicap = () => {
        alert("change handicap");

        //get member id

        //get new handicap value

        //get new socred value

        //Call api call to update handicaps and pass id, handicap and socred
    }

    const onChangeHandicap = () => {
    };

    const onChangeHandicapReduction = () => {

    }


   return (

//Code to show user details, including a button which opens the modal below

{/*Modal for changing handicap*/}
                <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>handicaps</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>Edit handicap for {props.user.firstname} {props.user.surname} </p>
                        <div className="mb-2">
                            <Input
                            value={props.user.handicap}
                            label={`Change handicap for ${props.user.firstname}`}
                            onChange={onChangeHandicap}
                            //hasError={props.errors.handicap && true}
                            //error={props.errors.handicap}
                            />
                            <Input
                            value={props.user.sochcpred}
                            label={`Change handicap reduction for ${props.user.firstname}`}
                            onChange={onChangeHandicapReduction}
                            //hasError={props.errors.sochcpred && true}
                            //error={props.errors.sochcpred}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" className="btn-danger" onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button variant="secondary" className="btn-success" onClick={updateHandicap}>Save</Button>
                        
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
```

So I need to update the `user.handicap` and `user.sochcpred` when the value changes in the respected input field. Then when I call the API to updateHandicap, pass these values as well as the current users id.

I have tried the following,

```
const onChangeHandicap = (event) => {
        //set a new user as the current user details
        const user = props.user;
        //keep a record of the original handicap value before changing
        let originalHandicap = myDataObject.originalHandicap;
        //If the originalHandicap is undefined, set it to the value of the users handicap
        if(originalHandicap === undefined){
            originalHandicap = user.handicap;
        }
        //Set the user from props handicap as the value from the form input field
        props.user.handicap = event.target.value;
        //Show the user details
        console.log(user);
    };
```

When I do this 2 things happen, the value in the input field never changes for example it is 3.9, it never changes from this when I change it, and 2 in the console output, only the value after the decimal point is changed, so if I press delete 3 times, it deletes the 9 but then always leaves `3.` if I add something, it adds the first value after `3.9` but no more. So I understand as soon as I make a change it is returned to the value of `3.9` due to the value being set like this `value={props.user.handicap}` but how can I update this value so I can use it to pass to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend that you read the official [React handbook page on forms.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) After that you might want to spend some time familiarizing yourself with the differences between state and props within a component.

When your component is being initialized, your data will come from the props being passed to it from its parent. Any changes to the data from parent components will also be passed through props.

But when you want to make internal changes, i.e. from a form input, those changes should be made to the component's state. Component state is a little bit tricky to visualize with functional components, but essentially the flow of props to state in a functional component should look a little like this:

```
const exampleComponent = (props) => {
    const [someData, setSomeData] = useState(props.someData)
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setSomeData(e.target.value)
    }
    return(
        <input type='text' value={someData} onChange={handleChange} />
    )
}
```

In this example, you can see that the initial value of `someData` is coming from your component's props, but when the internal changes are made they're made through the function `setSomeData`.

In your component, I would advise you to setup a flow from props to state like the one in my example, where each attribute if your user object is separated into it's own state variable (e.g. user.id use put into the state using `var [userId, setUserId] = useState(props.user.id)`), since setting state of nested objects can be annoying.

tl;dr: Changes from user input should be made to state. Read the react docs on state, the useState hook, and forms.